# Project Euler 10 Python

Tags: python

I've started learning Python 2 days ago and my friends said Project Euler is good to learn. I solved the first 9 Problems and although it was very hard it somehow worked every time. But now im stuck and I dont know why. My answer is just about 100000 off (doesnt seem that much when working with those huge numbers). So if one of you has the time to help me find my fault it would be highly appreciated.

```
x = 2
z = 0


def is_prime(x):
    if x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(2, 1415):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True


while x < 2000000:

    if is_prime(x) == True:
        z = z + x
        x = x + 1
    elif x >= 2000000:
        break
    else:
        x = x + 1

print(z)
```

Comment: You need to explain what this is supposed to do. We don't know what "Project Euler 10" means.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
You haven't included the problem you're solving, the actual and expected results, and your own debugging traces.  "100000 off" is not a problem specification.

Comment: You don't need `elif x >= 2000000: break`, since `while x < 2000000:` does the same check.

Comment: sorry guys im nee to this, ill be more specific next time. If you want to know just google Project Euler Problem 10 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your is_prime function is the source of your error, specifically,

```
for n in range(2, 1415)
```

This will say that no number below 1415 is prime because, for example, 7 is a prime number but is in the range 2-1414, so 7%7 is 0.

Keeping the same basic formatting, we can rewrite it as such, using math to calculate the square root for each number (which is where the 1415 came from). If you don't want to import math, you can make it range(2,x), but that will have a very long computation time.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(x))+1): # +1 is for how python handles ranges
        if (x % n) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

You can also clean up your code a little bit like this (keeping the same general format):

```
for x in range(2, 2000000+1): # again, +1 for how python handles ranges
    if is_prime(x): # you don't need == True, the True return makes the if statement True
        z += x

print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the function that verifies that the number is prime.

Here's a working function:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if (x<2):
        return False

    div = 2

    while (div < x):
        if (x%div == 0):
            return False
        div += 1
    return True
```

Edit:

Here's a way faster solution:

```
x = 2
z = 0

def is_prime2(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n & 1 == 0:
        return False
    d= 3
    while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
        d= d + 2
    return True
    
while x <= 2000000:

    if is_prime2(x) == True:
        z = z + x
        x = x + 1
    else:
        x = x + 1

print(z)
```

Comment: But that takes too long doesnt it? I need a faster check for the primes

Comment: @Salle I added a faster solution

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so i have a question... you run the code and what is happening? I copy-paste your code and i couldn't run it. So i have this solution for you if is not running

```
x = 2
z = 0


def is_prime(x):
    if x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(2, 1415):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True

is_prime = is_prime(x)
while x < 2000000:
    if is_prime == True:
        z = z + x
        x = x + 1
    elif x >= 2000000:
        break
    else:
        x = x + 1

print(z)
```

This is only if is not running. As the guys said on your comments be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Its running for me